# Possible mutual information of two coin flips.

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Let X be a fair coin flip and Y a coin flip with $p = \frac{1}{3}$. I want to find possible values of mutual information $I(X:Y)$ between them.

If they are independent then this value is $0$. But when i try to find an upper bound on the only way i see: writing down definitions, I meet unhandable mess of $log$s.

I have rough bound $min(H(X), H(Y))$ from $I(X,Y)=H(X)-H(X|Y)$ and $I(X,Y)=H(Y) - H(Y|X)$ but it is clearly not reached.

Comment: Why search for an upper bound when you can solve the problem *exactly*??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Can I? I had impression that if we change functions a bit we can get various results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to figure out all possible joint distributions of $(X,Y)$.  In this case there happens to be a very simple one-parameter family of possibilities.  For concreteness let's say that $P(X=0) = P(X=1) = 1/2$ and $P(Y=0) = 2/3$, $P(Y=1) = 1/3$.  In the joint distribution, let's say that $P(X=0,Y=0) = t$.  This forces us to have $P(X=1,Y=0) = 2/3-t$ and $P(X=0,Y=1) = 1/2 - t$ and $P(X=1,Y=1) = t-1/6$.  Also, each of these four numbers needs to be in $[0,1]$, which is only possible if $t \in [1/6, 1/2]$.  Thus we have a complete characterization of all possible joint distributions.

Now the calculation of $I(X,Y)$ is a simple calculation:
\begin{align*}
I(X,Y) &= H(X) + H(Y) - H(X,Y) \\
&= \log2 - (2/3)\log(2/3) - (1/3)\log(1/3) + t\log t + (1/2-t)\log(1/2-t) \\
&= \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ + (2/3-t)\log(2/3-t) + (t-1/6)\log(t-1/6).
\end{align*}

To see all the possible values this can take, you can just graph this on the interval $t \in [1/6, 1/2]$:

[image]

The zero is at $t=1/3$ which corresponds to $X$ and $Y$ being independent.  You can also figure out the maximum possible by plugging in $t=1/6$ or $t=1/2$ (with the usual convention that $0\log 0 = 0$).

**EDIT:** In hindsight, it should have been obvious that $I(X,Y)$ is maximized when $X$ a.s. determines $Y$ (corresponding to the edge cases $t=1/6$ or $t=1/2$).  So if all you care about is the maximum possible mutual information, the above is a lot of unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Adam pointed out to me that what I thought was  $H(Y \vert X)$ was in fact $KL( Y \vert \vert X)$.
The correct formula for  $H(Y \vert X)$ is
$$
\sum_{i \in \Omega} \sum_{j \in \Omega} \mathbb{P}(Y = i, X = j)) \log \left( \frac{\mathbb{P}(Y = i, X = j)}{\mathbb{P}(X = i)} \right) 
$$

This make the problem much more difficult, because we make no assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

---

Mutual information is a measure of how the entropies of the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are corelated. Our sample space is $\Omega = \{ 0, 1\}$. We have $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = 1/2$, $\mathbb{P}(Y = 1) = 1/3$. (By symmetry, it won't matter if heads or tails occurs with probability $1/3$ for the second coin.) We are now ready to calculate $I(X; Y)$. By definition, mutual information is the quantitiy
$I(X; Y) = H(Y) - H(Y \vert X )$.

$$H(Y) = - \sum_{i \in \Omega} \mathbb{P}(Y = i) \log \left( \mathbb{P}(Y = i) \right)  $$
$$ = - \left(2/3 \log{2/3} + 1/3 \log 1/3 \right) = 2/3 \log{3/2} + 1/3 \log 3.$$
Now we calculate relative entropy
$$ H(Y \vert X) =  \sum_{i \in \Omega} \mathbb{P}(Y = i) \log \left( \frac{\mathbb{P}(Y = i)}{\mathbb{P}(X = i)} \right) $$
$$ = - \left(2/3 \log{\frac{2/3}{1/2}} + 1/3 \log{\frac{1/3}{1/2}}  \right) = 2/3 \log{3/4} + 1/3 \log{3/2}$$
Putting everything together,
$$I(X; Y) = H(Y) - H(Y \vert X) = $$
$$2/3 \log{3/2} + 1/3 \log 3 - ( 2/3 \log{3/4} + 1/3 \log{3/2})$$
$$= 1/3 \log{3/2} - 1/3\log{3} + 2/3 \log{4}$$
(I think).

Comment: Your definition of relative entropy isn't correct; what you've written there is the KL divergence.  It's not possible to calculate $I(X,Y)$ exactly without knowing the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.

Comment: I see. My mistake. This is a bit more difficult than I thought. Do you want to post a solution @Adam ?

Comment: I'll work on it, but I don't know the answer yet!

Comment: I have posted an answer